# Opencsv parse last position till end as one string

Tags: java, opencsv

Using opencsv 4.0, I am writing data as below to file and sending it to external system
X,Y,Z

If external system fails to process we get error as below,
Syntax: error_code, Originally submitted text
1,X,Y,Z

Now I am using ColumnPositionMappingStrategy to parse this data from file. Is it possible to specify last position so that I get all originally submitted text as one string i.e, X,Y,Z.Right now when I am using ColumnPositionMappingStrategy I am only getting X and rest Y,Z is being ignored.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import com.opencsv.enums.CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator;

public class OpenCsvApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] memberFieldsToBindTo = { "errorCode", "rejectionText" };
    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Response> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
    strategy.setType(Response.class);
    strategy.setColumnMapping(memberFieldsToBindTo);

    String line = "1,X,Y,Z";
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(line);
    CsvToBeanBuilder<Response> csvBuilder = new CsvToBeanBuilder<>(reader);
    csvBuilder.withMappingStrategy(strategy);
    csvBuilder.withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true);   
    csvBuilder.withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.EMPTY_SEPARATORS);
    CsvToBean<Response> csvToBean = csvBuilder.build();
    Response response =  csvToBean.parse().get(0);
    reader.close();
    System.out.format("errorCode: %s, rejectionText: %s", response.getErrorCode(), response.getRejectionText());

}

 }
    public class Request {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }
    public void setField3(String field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
}`

public class Response {

private String errorCode;
private String rejectionText;
public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}
public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}
public String getRejectionText() {
    return rejectionText;
}
public void setRejectionText(String rejectionText) {
    this.rejectionText = rejectionText;
}
}
```

Output: errorCode: 1, rejectionText: X

I want to get rejectionText to be X,Y,Z

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help you if you include the code that configures and calls your parser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your output is not properly formatted.    Remember in a CSV file the comma is a delimeter so yes 1 will go into error code and X will go into rejection text and Y and Z will be lost because your response only has two fields and you passed in four.   If you want X,Y,Z to be one field you need to use quotes in your data so opencsv will know it is all one field.

```
"1","X,Y,Z"
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The output is coming from a external system which is black box to me. So I cant control the output format. I am trying to find if there is way to specify last position so that anything
after last specifed position should be considered as one string even though it had comma's in it.

Comment: If you really do not control the source then for what you want I would recommend NOT using any CSV library and instead just reading the string from the source, finding the first comma position and everything before that position put in your error code and everything after put in the rejection text.   Otherwise you can use the CSVReader and just read the array of Strings then put the first item in the array into the error code and use a string builder to combine all the other elements, adding back the delimiter, and put that result into the rejection text.